# How will each of Axiom's robots in Wall•E (besides AUTO, EVE, and WALL•E) be used on Earth?

Tags: wall-e

I am wondering what happens to The Axiom and its robots after the humans inhabited Earth again. Wall•E and EVE will love each other forever, while AUTO is useless on Earth.

Comment: Auto is a mono-maniacal psychopath. I assume they'll make him President

Answer (score 4):

**The various robots were forced into back-breaking servitude, until their inevitable deaths, as can be see in the film's final, horrifying, sequence.**

EVE is forced to dig irrigation ditches, Wall•E is made to use his welding laser to start camp-fires, [TYP-E](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/TYP-E) has to plant seeds, [D-FIB](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/D-FIB) is pulling in fishing nets, [PRT-E](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/PR-T) is seen taking care of children, [BRL-A](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/BRL-A) is waiting on humans and sheltering them from the sun, [SECUR-T](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/SECUR-T) bots are made to carry heavy loads of construction materials, [VN-GO](https://pixar.fandom.com/wiki/VN-GO) is painting interior walls, etc.

And as you can see in the final image, the Axiom never flies again. It's stripped of its lifepods and various useful parts and then left to rot.

Comment: Is there any time for Eve and Wall-E to meet up regularly?

Comment: @user144158 - Yes, you see them together in the final sequence, possibly hundreds of years later still all lovey-dovey.

Comment: Last of the surviving Axiom robots, living in a civilization not yet capable of rebuilding or repairing them. WALL-E running out of spares, EVE having few user-replaceable parts.

Comment: @notovny - Wall-E has spares from tens of thousands of other defunct Wall-E robots to play with. I'd imagine that he's effectively immortal.

Comment: @Valorum Except without maintenance, those spares will break…